# Filtering SQL results by latest date starting on a Monday

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, date

I am selecting information from 4 different tables in a MS SQL database. I have filtered the information to where I now need to only select the latest tables where the date is closest to `GETDATE()` current Monday. 
For example, say I pull through this information currently:

```
 Date           | StockCode
----------------+----------             
18/08/2014      | ABC123  
11/08/2014      | 321CBA  
04/08/2014      | 321CBA   
28/07/2014      | ABC123    
11/08/2014      | ABC123
28/07/2014      | TEST123
```

I need to filter it to show this result:

```
Date            | StockCode
----------------+----------
18/08/2014      | ABC123   
11/08/2014      | 321CBA   
28/07/2014      | TEST123
```

Thanks for all your help! Much appreciated.

Comment: Last row value for StockCode is `ABC123` or `TEST123`?

Comment: Your verbal description is unclear to me, and in such cases I try to derive the meaning from the example. However, your example doesn't help much either. Why is `04/08/2014` not in the results? Why is the `28/07/2014` entry has `ABC123` in `StockCode`?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, the last row value for the Stock Code is supposed to be TEST123 and not ABC123. Also, I apologize if I seem unclear, the problem is quite complex and for me to try and explain it is difficult. To answer your question @AndriyM, 04/08/2014 with stock code 321CBA is not in the results because 11/08/2014 with the same stock code is newer. I hope that helps and thanks again for everyones help!

Comment: Then this seems to be a simple GROUP BY problem. Have you tried grouping and aggregation already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
declare @Monday datetime= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 0)

Select StockCode,aa.Date
From TableName Main
     OUTER APPLY (Select top 1 Datefrom TableName t 
                where t.StockCode=Main.StockCode
                order by DATEDIFF(d,Date,@Monday)) as aa
Group By StockCode,aa.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this will depend on how many results you want to be returned by your query and what you consider to be "close" to the date.

If you wanted to find the 5 dates closest before and after the desired date (in this case Monday of the current week) then this would work:

```
SELECT TOP 5 
Date,  
StockCode
FROM Table 
Order by abs(datediff("d", Date, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0))
```

Comment: Why you selecting top 5?

Comment: Perhaps I've misread the question NgNoob didn't specify how many results he wanted to be returned.

Comment: I don't need a specific number of results returned. I need the latest/most recently made entries to be returned as shown in the example.

Comment: Should the third stockcode in your expected output have been "TEST123"?